# AdoNetAppender get connectionstring value from another file

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, log4net, adonetappender

I have multiple web services that currently logs their info\error messages using log4net into file.
I want the logging now to be done in DB. I've read about AdoNetAppender and I can see that given some parameters such as command text and connection string it can be easily done.

BUT - my connection string is not in the same web.config as the log4net but is taken from config.ini in disk. Can I configure the AdoNetAppender so it'll extract the value of the connection string from there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved by this link:

http://www.megustaulises.com/2012/12/set-log4net-connection-string-at-runtime.html

Comment: This link is dead.